# Event Time field is defaulted to 12 AM

Tags: lightning, custom-button, urlhacking, custom-url

[image]Event Time field is defaulted to 12 AM
I have a requirement to prepopulate the Time field on event object to system time, im using the below formula but time field is defaulted to 12 AM. Unable to change it. As it is a requiredc field cant even remove from the layout.

/lightning/o/Event/new?recordTypeId=************8&defaultFieldValues=
ActivityDateTime={!NOW()}

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are trying to setup this URL in a Spring '20 release org, because this feature does not exist in previous releases.

Also, there is a syntax issue in your URL, according to the [release note](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_general_lex_navigate_to_record_dfv.htm) the fields must be comma-separated after `defaultFieldValues` like this example:

```
/lightning/o/Event/new?defaultFieldValues=
RecordTypeId=012B0000000RByrIAG,
Location=1234,
Subject=Call,
ActivityDateTime={!NOW()}
```

Now, I tried to create a button with that link but neither the fields `ActivityDateTime` nor `StartDateTime` seems to be allowed to be set as default values, getting an error when saving the event, refer to screenshot below.

You mentioned that the Start date/time was defaulting to 12AM, this is a standard behaviour which calculates the start date/time to the next hour, so that the start of an event default to later than current time.

**Conclusion**: 
It seems that this new Spring '20 feature has some limitations for this use case and does not allow to default the start field of an event.

**Workaround**:
You can setup a quick action button instead where the RecordTypeId is defaulted and under "Predefined Field Values", start time field is set to formula `NOW()`. This works fine. 
Note that in this case, the button will appear under Activity tab of the object record page.

[image]

Comment: Hi Shamina, There is no problem with spring 20 features, This URL is working fine  /lightning/o/Event/new?recordTypeId=************8&defaultFieldValues= ActivityDateTime={!NOW()}   But, the problem im facing is on the Event standard object , event page layout , Time field (not the start date and time) which is a required field, it is defaulted to 12 AM, im unable to change the default time, of the Time field which is of date/time datetype.

Comment: Does this mean that you managed to make it work with same URL? thats strange because i got different behavior in a developer org under spring 20

Comment: Does the activity start time defaults to now and have you tried saving the event successfully?

Comment: Initially i have given the same formula as yours, but the record type is picked as default record type. We cannot pass the record type under default field values.

Comment: That is the issue im facing, even after giving activitydatetime=now Time field still shows 12 Am

Comment: Yes activitydatetime will not change. But still try to save the event record and see if you get similar error message like the 1 I've posted

Comment: No i don't see any error as seen in the picture, I guess you are using the developer edition, because the page layout looks different.

Comment: If it's just a Time field, try using {!TIMENOW()} instead of {!NOW()} ?

Comment: yep, tried that too. no change.